# CSS filter: blur(0px) still blurs the text

Tags: css, filter, blur

I want to blur a part of my website which gets unblurred by clicking on a link. To make this smooth I need to apply blur(0px) and get a transition on the element. The problem though is that the text gets unsharp even with blur(0px).

```
.page.blurred {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.page {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);

  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

I toggle the class with jQuery.
Any suggestions how to deal with it?

Comment: What do you mean blur? Blur is an jquery event handle, so it mean when you lost focus your element! Do you mean opacity?

Comment: @hicurin `filter` is a CSS property which accepts a value of `blur([pixels])`. This can be used to give text a blurred effect. (http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/FJxNv/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting issue. One fix to this would be to set the `filter` property to `initial`, thus resetting the filter completely:

```css
elem {
    -webkit-filter: initial;
    filter: initial;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/FJxNv/2/) showing the difference between both. The top text resets the filter to `initial` whereas the bottom text sets the filter to `blur(0)` (which is equivalent to using `blur(0px`; the top text goes back to normal, whereas the bottom text retains the font rendering of blur.

Comment: That does make the text sharp again, but isn't working combined with transition. The smooth transition only works with blur(0px) so far...

Comment: @MarcelKrebs it does work with transition in Chrome. Which browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/FJxNv/4

Comment: I am using Chrome right now. Mhh is the jQuery toggle of the .blurred class the problem?

Comment: @MarcelKrebs I can't replicate the problem. If you click the text the transition still works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/FJxNv/5/